# Opening a project in landscape in iOS doesn't display correctly in Delphi XE8

Tags: ios, delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe8

When I open my projects in landscape in iOS the form appears to be rotated 90 degrees to the right and also doesn't fit in the screen.

When I open it in portrait I don't get any problems. Also when I then turn it to landscape, it displays correctly.

Does anyone have a solution for this?

**UPDATE:**
I've downloaded XCode 5.1.1 so I can compile iOS 7.1
This solves the rotation issue, but now it doesn't fill the whole screen.

Comment: Take a look at [iOS application starts always in portrait mode](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-9566) and [Landscape apps in portrait with Xcode 6.1](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-9664)

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar Thanks for the links! Should be resolved in XE7 though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using FXG component ActivityDialog. I used this component in the formCreate method which gave the problem. By removing it from the formCreate and moving it to the formActivate the problem is solved.

Answer (score 3):

This is apparently a bug in XE8, which seems to happen mainly in larger programs, and possibly in combination with TMS iCL components. At least no one has yet made a small program that can reproduce the problem. I have also had the problem, and I "solved" it with a workaround.

See [this bug report](http://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-10313) and [this forum question](https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?threadID=115542) (if you can catch it while the servers are up). Both describe various fixes and workarounds.

**Edit:**
I was able to reproduce the bug in a small program and it seems at least the iCL FMX wrapper can cause this error to happen. Also it happens only when target is iOS 8. I contacted TMS and they confirmed that they can reproduce it and will fix it. Until then, you can solve it by creating the wrapper first time it is shown:

```
TForm = class
  ...
  fWrapper: TTMSFMXNativeFMXWrapper;
  ...
end;

procedure TForm.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if not Assigned(fWrapper) then
  begin
    fWrapper := TTMSFMXNativeFMXWrapper.Create(Self);
    fWrapper.Form := MyWrappedFMXForm;
    fWrapper.Parent := MyParentView;
  end;
end;
```